# Binary: How to save .csv to binary .dat

Tags: binary

I have some .csv file. The question is how to save it in binary .dat file?

Example of such file we can take on the page:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

It will be good if it can be done in shell or PHP.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a GeoLite database in .csv format, you can do different things with it:

1. Split it into the different datasets as in the different GeoLite .dat dataset files.
2. Use the other existing GeoLite .dat files (regions, countries, etc.) and generate the .dat file with the dataset you need in .dat format based on the relevant information your .csv file, and referencing the other datasets.

The CSV-File is in 1st normal form, and the .dat datasets (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/) seem to be in 3rd normal form, so datasets of some type seem to depend on datasets of other types.

Sorry, I can not give a better answer to your requirements without more precise information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Look I use GeoIP database but it's not right. I found more fresh db but in CSV. CSV file takes more disk space than DAT file. And seem the system will work more faster with DAT. That's why I need to find some approach to save GeoIP data in DAT file.

Comment: I didn't succeed in finding out what's the structure of those .dat files, so I can not provide any implementation for a converter.